# Where is my SharePoint Online Data Stored

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, server, cdn

The question came up yesterday about our company's data and where it is stored physically. We have Content Delivery Networks setup on some document libraries which as I understand it are distributed and localized. But I have no idea where our actual site collection & tenant data are stored.

How can we find out the physical location of the servers in which our O365 environment is stored? 
Is it on one server or is it redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to check the data location, you need to login the admin center of Office 365 with global admin account. and browse to [company profile](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/companyprofile).

```
Admin center > settings > Company profile > data location > View details.
```

[image]